# how to create variables from list1 and assign values from list2 to the same variables using pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have 2 lists list 1 and list 2

```
path1=/mnt/path1
path2=/mnt/path2
path3=/mnt/path3

list1=['value1','value2','value3']
list2=['/mnt/path1','/mnt/path2','/mnt/path3']
```

I want to create variables from list 1 and assign the values from list2 to those variables

```
**output:**
value1=/mnt/path1
value2=/mnt/path2
value3=/mnt/path3
```

where value1,value2,value3 are variables

```
If I do print(value1)
I need to get output as '/mnt/path1'
```

how to achieve this using pyspark

Comment: pyspark or python? are the lists in a dataframe or RDD for pyspark use?

Comment: pyspark , thy are in RDD

Comment: in that case, please share how the RDDs look like

Comment: while we await your rdd structure, here's my $.2 -- you won't be able to create variables dynamically (at least not simply). the next best option is to use a dict where the keys can act as variable names and the values of the keys as the required value

Answer (score 0):

@harshith

I have taken dummy data

```
Solution

data=[("1",),("2",),("3",)]
schema=["id"]
df=spark.createDataFrame(data,schema)
list1=['value1','value2','value3']
list2=['/mnt/path1','/mnt/path2','/mnt/path3']
fnl_lst =  list(zip(list1,list2))
columns_mapping = [F.lit(fnl_lst[i][j]) for  i in range(len(list2)) for j in range(2)]
map_column = F.create_map(*columns_mapping)
df=df.withColumn("path_mapping",map_column)
df.select("id","path_mapping.value1").show(10,0)
```

Kindly upvote if like my solution  or Do let me know if you  have any questions around this.